# LineageOS build getting stuck / building specific module with mm is stuck

Tags: android-source, lineageos

It is an interesting behavior - so I'm posting this if anyone else will ever encounter this.

The symptom is that issuing 'brunch DEVICE' command is stuck, as well as issuing the 'mm' command to build a specific module

Answer (score 1):

This happened because of permissions issue - I previously attempted to build from a root user, so when trying to build from a regular user - the build process is getting stuck
a simple `sudo chown -R USER out` will resolve the issue.